# SDL_FINGERDOWN gives wrong cursor position on MultiTouch,OSX

Tags: c++, macos, sdl, sdl-2

Device: Macbook, OS X, multitouch, SDL2.

```
float posX = event.tfinger.x; 
float posY = event.tfinger.y; 
if ( event.type == SDL_FINGERDOWN ) std::cout << "posX = " << posX << ", posY = " <<  posY << "\n";
```

It returns me coordinates of my multitouch device. If I tap my multitouch at the left-top corner it returns me coordinates something like 0.1x0.1. Ok, right. But how to get coordinates of the cursor position in OS X?

I can get only coordinates of multitouch device but it doesn't mean that it's the coordinates of the cursor on the screen. I mean... I can tap my multitouch at the left-top corner but my cursor at this time will be at the right-bottom corner of the screen.

Comment: looks like some sort of a bug

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get both the point where you touch the device, and where the cursor on the screen is?

I'd recommend using the SDL_MOUSEMOTION event:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
   switch(e->type) {
   case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
       mouseX = e.button.x;
       mouseY = e.button.y;
       break;
   }
}
```

where the "mouseX" and "mouseY" variables will be the coordinates of the cursor on the screen *within the SDL_Window*.

If you want the *global* mouse coordinates, you can use SDL_GetGlobalMouseState:

```
int mouseX;
int mouseY;
SDL_GetGlobalMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
```

which will get you the global (relative to the desktop) coordinates.

Currently there is a bug with SDL_GetMouseState where if you use SDL_SetWindowFullscreen and set it to borderless fullscreen (SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP) it gets the wrong coordinates, which is why I recommed use of the SDL_MOUSEMOTION event instead.
It's fine to use in any other instance (as far as I can tell).